# convert vector into a string and split the string for JSP

Tags: string, jsp, vector

I need to know how to convert vector into a string and split the string for JSP.

```
// Make sure that you use the same path/filename that youâ€™ve saved earlier
    Vector<String[]> vec1 = FileReaderWriter.readFileToVector        ("?/MyTestFile.txt");
    String vec2 = vec1.toString();  
    String split[] = vec2.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) 
    {
        // out.print("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < vec1.elementAt(i).length; j++) 
        {
 //         out.print(vec1.elementAt(i)[j] + ",");  
            //out.print("blah");
//          fieldlist.add(vec1.elementAt(i)[j]);

            out.print("<br/>");
        }
        //out.print("blah");
```

The problem is the output is gibberish, it is not printing what is in the vector.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting Vector to string and splitting it, why not loop over the list in JSP using `<c:foreach>`. I would recommend not to use scriptlets.